# visual studio 2010 solution navigator/solution explorer background

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible somehow to chenge background on solution navigator/solution explorer in visual studio 2010 ?

I did change default environment scheme and now i would like to have the same background in solution navigator/solution explorer is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. This is BUG. See [Solution Explorer background](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534052/solution-explorer-background-color-is-white-instead-of-using-windows-color).

Answer (score 2):

Just created VS extension for that in under an hour, search extension manager for "SExColor". Enjoy ;)